# Which Class is better and why

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am looking into move-semantics, I want to know which class is better and why. I tried counting the number of allocations in both(by overloading new operator).
t1 will allocate only once, t2 will allocate twice.
By the looks of it, t1 seems more optimized but does this has some shortcomings.

```
class Test1
{
    std::string&& s;  
public:
       Test1(std::string&& n) 
   :s(std::move(n)) {} 
};

   class Test2
{
     std::string s;
public:
   Test2(std::string&& n) 
   :s(std::move(n)) {} 
};


int main()
{
   Test1 t1("sdfds");
   Test2 t2("SDf");     
    }
```

Comment: `Test1` contains only a reference to the temporary string that was constructed as argument to its constructor, which died as soon as said constructor finished and left said reference dangling.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, Yeah right!

Comment: This may not be any help, and I'm not an expert on C++ move semantics, but when I got back into C++, I created a project on github while I worked some of it out. It's available as https://github.com/jplflyer/CPP-Move-Semantics. I can't vouch I'm doing everything optimally, however.

Comment: How did you measure allocations? Even without enabling compiler optimizations, both GCC and Clang do no dynamic memory allocation for your code (short string optimization): https://godbolt.org/z/UIVbF6 And even with longer strings, both lines in `main` make only one allocation: https://godbolt.org/z/Kttrus

Comment: No they don't. I am using msvc 2019: in degug build.                                                                                             make a static var: static unit32_t allocCount = 0;                                                                   void* operator new(size_t size)                                                                                { std::cout<<"alloc count "<<++allocCount;                                                          
  return malloc(size);}

Comment: @johnjakal I don't have any means to test msvc locally, however pasting the code from the links I gave above into https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual (which supposedly uses msvc, although a different version) I get the same results. I don't know flags I should add to correctly mimic debug build mode.

Comment: "*No they don't.*": They do, at least on gcc and clang. Do you disagree with how I measured it? It should also be at most one allocation, because no copy constructors or modification methods are called in your code. Therefore the only allocation is in the initially constructed `std::string` for the `Test1`/`Test2` constructor parameters. The move constructor for the member should not need to make dynamic allocations.